# How to store a hashedpassword in mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, hash, bcrypt

Im trying to store a hashed password in mongoDB, but in all my tries it sends in plain text or stays in a loop

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMfJs.png)

[service.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIBVg.png)

[auth.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF14J.png)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it

```js
function update(id, password) {

    console.log(password)
         
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            hashed = updatePassword(password)

            UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {password:hashed}, function(err, users) {
                    if (err) reject(err);

                    resolve(users);

            });
       
    }); 
        
 }

    function updatePassword( user ) {

        return  bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, config.saltRounds)
       
    }
```